# JSON posting data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have JSON data being added like this:

```
{
  "Name": "ghngjnghj",
  "Email": "jhjhj@jkbjvk.com",
  "Message": "hjhjhj"
}
```

But I need to format it like this:

```
jsonCallback(
   {
 "Name": "ghngjnghj",
  "Email": "jhjhj@jkbjvk.com",
  "Message": "hjhjhj"

     }

);


url: "post_json.aspx",
data: $("#contact_form").serialize(),
```

Also i'm using JSON.Net in my code behind

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JSON\dotNet4b\test_file.json", json);
```

Comment: do you want a jsonp response?

Comment: Thanks! this is a POST JSON function. But the GET data callback is JSONP cheers P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change string json like so!

string json = "jsonCallback(\n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented) + "\n);";

HTH someone